# Reading data from the database and displaying it in a text field

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset, sqldataadapter

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(
        "Data Source=PTZ1\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog = test; Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID=sa; Password=sa@; Trusted_Connection=True;");

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from testing", conn);
        adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
        adapter.Fill(ds, "First Table");

       foreach (DataTable tables in ds.Tables)
        {
            ListBox1.Items.Add(tables.TableName);

        }
       conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Error in execution " + ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

}

I have the following program where I'm reading the values from the table and want to display the table values in a text field upon button click. Now when I click on the button, it just keeps on displaying **first table** in the listbox.

Can someone guide me through my error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you need to display the Values existing in the `DataRow` of a `DataTable`. In the code snippet below, columnName is referring to the `Column` of the `testing Table`, that you want to show in the `ListBox`.

```
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["First Table"].Rows)
{
    ListBox1.Items.Add(row["columnName"].ToString());
}
```

OR

```
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    ListBox1.Items.Add(row["columnName"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Working like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

`tables.TableName` gives the name  of the table which is "First Table" itself.So,it keeps on showing the same.

Better use this code.

```
    if(!ds.Tables.Count>1)
 { 
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows) 
{
        ListBox1.Items.Add(row["columnName"].ToString());
 } 
}
```

Comment: @FurqanSafdar yes because the answer is the same:=)

Comment: @FurqanSafdar: Just proves you're probably right. Its ok, I +1ed you both (you were first and I think it is important to vote for and encourage low rep users). ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from testing", conn);
            MySqlDataReader msqlreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (msqlreader.Read())
            { 
            listBox1.Items.Add(msqlreader(0);
            }
```

Im not sure if this is what you need, but hope it helps